# React Storybook. Error: Minified React error #31

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have a simple component

`footer.component.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';

const Footer: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
  return <div>CMP Ltd 2020, All rights reserved.</div>;
};

export default Footer;
```

and `footer.stories.ts`

```
import Footer from './footer.component';

export default {
  title: 'ButtonComponent'
};

export const primary = () => ({
  moduleMetadata: {
    imports: []
  },
  component: Footer
});
```

Whenever I run the storybook I get this error

```
Minified React error #31; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7BmoduleMetadata%2C%20component%2C%20props%7D&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

I can't figure out why. Any idea?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Honestly I can't even remember. We're using Nrwl now all is good.

Comment: Yeah, we are also using Nx (if that’s what you mean) and facing this issue :) It seems storybook creates production builds...